# Как правильно согласовать число слова "оттенок" при перечне оттенков: желтая с синим и серым оттенками или желтая с синим и серым оттенком?

Tags: согласование

Как правильно согласовать число слова "оттенок" при перечне оттенков: желтая с синим и серым оттенками  или желтая с синим и серым оттенком?

Comment: Удобнее ставить обобщающее слово в начале перечисления. Тогда вопросов не возникает. 

*Жёлтая с синим*. Смешение этих основных цветов даёт зелёный. Жёлтая с серым — с сажей и белилами — тоже зелёный. Здесь активные, влияющие на цветность, — оттенки жёлтого и синего. Формулу поменял бы на *серую с оттенками жёлтого и синего* и уточнял бы для ясности, например: *светло-серую с лимонно-жёлтым и голубым оттенками*. Ваш случай: *золотисто-жёлтая с приглушёнными изумрудным и травяным оттенками*.

Answer (score 1):

Оттенок — не неисчисляемое существительное. Следовательно, оно склоняется:
*...желтая с синим и серым оттенк**ами***.

Однако здесь ещё зависит от того, относите ли вы синий к основному цвету (наряду с жёлтым) или к оттенкам. Сравните:

- *Стена жёлтая с синим // и (с) серым оттенк**ом*** = основной цвет: жёлтый
  с синим, а серый — оттенок;
- *Стена жёлтая // с синим и серым оттенк**ами*** = основной цвет: жёлтый,
  оттенки: синий и серый.